# Abstract classes and Concrete Classes

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns

I´d like to know...

I know that an abstract class, is used for interface purpose.

What about the concrete class? It is the one who subclasses the abstract class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concrete class is a class that can be instantiated, as opposed to abstract classes, which cannot.

Answer (score 0):

A concrete class,  is a class for which entities (instances) may be created. unlike abstract class, Concrete classes have no virtual member functions or protected members. concrete exist in reality.